# GWT SimplePager issues

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT's (2.5) SimplePager class in my application, to display pre-loaded data (I know the exact row count in advance).

The issue is with the last page. Given I have, for instance, 42 elements with an initial visible range of 10.
First page is 1-10, second 11-20, third 21-30, fourth, 31-40.
The issue is that fifth page is not 41-42 (which I want, because I want to be able to scroll back and forth and "land" *exactly* on the same data) but 33-42.

I have tried various tinkering with overriding SimplePager / AbstractPager methods, with no success.
For instance, if I override setPageStart, do the same as com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractPager.setPageStart(int) but with the following commented out (I think it is the culprit code):

```
if (isRangeLimited && display.isRowCountExact()) {
  index = Math.min(index, display.getRowCount() - pageSize);
}
```

The last page is fine (41-42), but this erases page size forever and when I go from last page to previous page, it becomes 40-41 (expected: 31-40). This is probably because the page size is not some constant provided to the pager instance, but is calculated with the Range object which was last used ("int pageSize = range.getLength();" in setPageStart method).

Any clue on modifying the paging behavior to my needs without breaking anything ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got a working solution which is simple enough.
I provided a page size (which is the maximum number of elements that could be displayed, regardless of the total number of elements available to display) to my SimplePager object. Then I overrided getPage(), hasNextPage(), hasNextPages(int), hasPreviousPages(int), nextPage(), previousPage(), setPageStart(int) to use the provided page size instead of getLength() on the Range object.

To test this more easily (still done by hand...) I used GWT's Showcase project (and ran it in dev mode).

The downside is that I had to copy the code of the overriden methods (from AbstractPager - SimplePager does nothing except calling the superclass' methods) into my Pager class.